# How to calculate torque at the end of a lever arm?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, torque, moment-of-inertia

I am messing around with creating small computer simulations to self study. Last time I did physics was in high school.

Consider the setup below. An electric motor (black) is spinning a metal disk (green). The motor is at the end of an arm that can revolve. I would like to set the RPM for the motor and the system react like it would in real live. The disk should accelerate causing the arm to revolve.

I believe I can find the torque applied to the motor by accelerating metal disk with the following (I have the moment of inertia of the motor and metal disk and the angular acceleration of the disk):
$$T=I*\omega/t$$

[image]

What I am struggling with is to convert this torque, at the end of the arm into a force and then to calculate the torque this would produce at the center point.

I think if I could find the force magnitude and the force normal is 90 degrees to the arm I could use the following to find the torque applied at the center point.
$$T=f*d$$

Summary: I want to find the torque produced at the center point of the system when the metal disk is spun up or down.

Comment: Voting to reopen. This is obviously not a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: Hint: Use conservation of angular momentum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newton's 3rd law dictates that if a torque $T_{\rm m}$ is applied to the disk from the motor, then an equal and opposite torque $\mbox{-}T_{\rm m}$ is applied to the motor.

[image: fig1]

At the same time, the connection allows radial force $F_{\rm r}$ as well as a tangential force $F_{\rm t}$ applied to the disk and has also equal and opposite forces acting on the motor.

This is the way to model this system, as the equations of motion require the calculation of the net force on each body, as well as the net torque about the center of mass.

Since the bodies are not free-bodies the motion of each body is dictated by the kinematics of the pin joints. This means the acceleration of the center of mass of each body depends on the orientation of each joint, as well as the rotational speeds of the joints.

The mathematics are a bit complex to explain here to someone without a background in dynamics at a college level. Thankfully there are a lot of free online college notes on this topic.